# Internet Explorer Layout Bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, layout

I am working on a website which works fine in Chrome and Firefox but doesn't display right in Internet Explorer (all versions). Here's what it looks like in all three browsers:

[image: Chrome and Firefox]
Chrome and Firefox

[image: Internet Explorer (all versions)]
Internet Explorer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some relevant code (and maybe a JSFiddle example) here. With only an external link, the question will have no value to future readers once the problem is solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a space between your DOCTYPE and your html that is preventing IE from applying a proper DOCTYPE declaration. The DOCTYPE needs to be in the absolute top of your document with no spaces. Remove that and your page should work fine.

---

You can see the error [[here]](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fvnaas.com%2Fsupport_customer.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2) in the validation report

Important bit:

```
Line 1, Column 1: character "" not allowed in prolog
```

Comment: Got rid of the spaces, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with this line:

```
<div style="left: 0px; top: 150px; position: fixed;" sizset="45" sizcache07028310558890892="0">
```

In IE, it's rendering with `position: fixed` but in all other browsers it's rendering with `position: absolute`.

**Note:** It would be helpful to let people know that you're using browser specific CSS.

Comment: @Daniel, re-read my answer. I did not fix your problem, I told you where your problem was. Are you using conditional CSS?

Comment: Yes, <!--[if lt IE 7]>
 <link href="css/ie_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->

Comment: Exactly. Again, re-read my answer, and fix your positioning issues.

Comment: It should be "position:fixed" for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Found the wrong line.
In CSS use

```
body { min-width: 950p; }
```

instead

```
html { ... }
```

Comment: Yeah, but html does not have a CSS property "min-width". So html { min-width: 950px; } is wrong.